# Confusion regarding regex pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have tried to write a regex to catch certains words in a sentence but it is not working. The below regex is only working when I give a exact match.

```
[\s]*((delete)|(exec)|(drop\s*table)|(insert)|(shutdown)|(update)|(\bor\b))
```

Lets say I send a HTTP Header - `headerName = insert` it works,

but does not work when I give `headerName = awesome insert number`

--edit--

@user1180, Yes I can use prepared statements, but we are also looking into the regex part.

@Marcel and Wiktor, yes it is working in that website. I guess my tool is not recognizing the regex. I am using Mulesoft ESB, which uses `Matches when the evaluated value fits a given regular expression (regex), specifically a regex "flavor" supported by Java.`

It is using something like this,
`matches /\+(\d+)\s\((\d+)\)\s(\d+\-\d+)/` and I am not aware of how to write my usecase in this regex format.

My usecase is too catch SQL injection pattern, which would check the request header/queryparam for `delete (exec)(drop\s*table)(insert)(shutdown)(update)or` parameters.

Comment: What is the full list of words/terms which you want to match?

Comment: It does work for me. See this [example](https://regex101.com/r/ZR3vjr/2)

Comment: These look like SQL statements. Are yo trying to prevent injection? If so, it is normally better to use prepared statements.

Comment: Are you using `matches` method in Java and the like?

Comment: So you just need to wrap the pattern with `(?s).*(<YOUR PATTERN>).*`. Try `(?s).*\b(delete|exec|drop\s+table|insert|shutdown|update|or)\b.*`

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor it is working. Please keep it as an answer, I will accept it. BTW do you recommend any material/site for learning regex as a newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regex must match the whole input you need to wrap the pattern with `.*`, something similar to `(?s).*(<YOUR PATTERN>).*`.

Use

```
(?s).*\b(delete|exec|drop\s+table|insert|shutdown|update|or)\b.*
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - turns on DOTALL mode where `.` matches any char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\b(delete|exec|drop\s+table|insert|shutdown|update|or)\b` - any one of the whole words (note `\b` is a word boundary construct) in the group
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible

I also replaced `drop\s*table` with `drop\s+table` since I guess `droptable` is not expected.

Comment: Thanks for the details. BTW what should be added to the above regex for case-insensitive matching?

Comment: i hope this works `(?s).*\b(?i)(delete|exec|drop\s+table|insert|shutdown|update|or)\b.*`

Comment: @JohnSeen `(?si).*\b(delete|exec|drop\s+table|insert|shutdown|update|or)\b.*`